# HTML5 audio problems

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio, mp3, html5-audio

I have a HTML5 audio player on my website, it is not working, however it works in all browsers except chrome.

```
<audio controls>
     <source src="http://www.mywebsite.com/path/2015-09-27.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

However a week or more ago the audio files did work, and I didn't change anything, they just stopped being able to be played.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with a mp3 file. I converted the `*.mp3` file to `*.ogg` (e.g. with [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org)) and added a second source to the audio tag:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="file.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Now everything works fine.

(found at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp))